# How to have my mouse wheel scroll the screen on zsh?

Tags: terminal, zsh

I use zsh 5.0.2 on Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS via SSH with Tera Term 4.84.
My .zshrc is here (my username is replaced with $USERNAME):

```
# Lines configured by zsh-newuser-install
HISTFILE=~/.zsh_history
HISTSIZE=50
SAVEHIST=50
bindkey -e
# End of lines configured by zsh-newuser-install
# The following lines were added by compinstall
zstyle :compinstall filename '/home/$USERNAME/.zshrc'

autoload -Uz compinit
compinit
# End of lines added by compinstall

PROMPT="%n@%m:%c%# "
```

In my shell, when I rotate the mouse wheel,
the command history moves instead of scrolling the screen.

Zsh 4.3.17 on another host (Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS)
can be scrolled well with mouse wheel with the same client.

How can I make my zsh scrolled with my mouse wheel without pressing the Ctrl key?

---

This question is also asked here (in Japanese): http://dixq.net/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=15586

Comment: Sounds rather like a terminal emulator problem, not zsh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @jimmij pointed out, this is an issue with Tera Term, not `zsh`.

According to the [Tera Term documentation](http://ttssh2.sourceforge.jp/manual/en/setup/teraterm-misc.html#mousewheel) there are 2 configuration options that control the behavior of the mouse's scroll wheel: `TranslateWheelToCursor` and `DisableWheelToCursorByCtrl`. Their default values are:

```
TranslateWheelToCursor=on
DisableWheelToCursorByCtrl=on
```

Setting `TranslateWheelToCursor=off` should disable the default scroll wheel behavior.